# Running a block of code on every interval except the first iteration

Tags: c#, optimization

I am working with an encryption algorithm that looks like this

1. The key is a number stored in 4 bytes.
2. For each byte in the message, XOR it with the corresponding byte in the key
3. When you reach the end of the key, multiply the key by 13, and then continue looping

Translated, it looks like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++) {

   // Increase the key as per the algorithm
   if (i > 0 && (i % 4 == 0)) {
      key *= 13
   }

   // Shift over i bytes, as per the algorithm
   data[i] ^= key >> (8 * (i % 4));
}
```

What I don't like is that check for `i > 0`, as it looks like wasteful processing. How can I modify this code so that I don't have that extra check that is basically redundant after the first iteration of the loop?

If the size of the data is 5 MB I don't want to run an extra 5 million or so `i > 0` checks when `i` is always increasing.

Comment: It should be an easy branch prediction, so I wouldn't expect it to influence actual performance. (But profile both ways to be certain.)

Comment: Performance-wise it may be negligible, but for future maintenance, it might also benefit to not have a weird check in there. I've found myself adding an extra, seemingly redundant check in several of my loops because I wasn't sure how to deal with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initialize the first byte, and then start the loop from 1.....

You may also want to do a bit-check instead of modulo, but they may be equally fast...

```
if (dataSize > 0) {
    data[0] ^= key;
}
for (int i = 1; i < dataSize; i++) {

   // Increase the key as per the algorithm
   if (i & 3 == 0) {
      key *= 13
   }

   // Shift over i bytes, as per the algorithm
   data[i] ^= key >> (8 * (i % 4));
}
```

### EDIT:

I have seen the following done (translating from memory of a C program)... this has been known to be able to compile down to SIMD-using instructions on supporting compilers, etc.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataSize - 3; i+=4) {

   // Shift over i bytes, as per the algorithm
   data[i + 0] ^= key; // >> (   0);
   data[i + 1] ^= key >> (   8);
   data[i + 2] ^= key >> (  16);
   data[i + 3] ^= key >> (  24);

   key *= 13

}

// handle up to 3 remaining bytes.....
for (int i = dataSize - (dataSize & 3); i < dataSize; i++) {
    data[i] ^= key >> (8 * (i & 3));
}
```

Comment: Consider also avoiding the other modulus (`data[i] ^= key >> ((i & 3) << 3);`), depending on what profiling says.

Comment: @MichaelUrman -- I was just thinking that... and I edited my post.... comments?

Comment: There is one C# specific performance issue with loop unrolling: The JITter can eliminate bounds checks for the standard loop `for(int i=0; i < array.Length; i++)`, but it can't with most other patterns. In this case it's probably still beneficial, but often it's not.